# Is it possible to pull additional info from LDAP during pam_ldap authentication?

Tags: pam, ldap

I have additional ldap data that I'd like to store in the user's home when they first log into a client using `pam_ldap`. However, I can't seem to think of a way to make this work without prompting the user to re-enter their ldap password after logging in.

I thought of using `pam_exec`, but I don't know how the client would authenticate to LDAP within `pam_exec` without first knowing the user's  LDAP password.

Are there any other possible solutions? I understand kerberos is probably better suited for this, but everything I've read about its complexity has made me avoid it like the plague.

Comment: Well, `expose_authtok` would give you the password, wouldn't it?

Comment: I completely missed that in the docs! Thanks, I'll give it a try.